# Laravel different controller for route if authenticated?

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel

I tried this:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@getIndex');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::controller('/',            'HomeController'); 
});
```

But it is always requiring login.

I want the PageController@getIndex to be called when visiting '/' when logged in, and HomeController (@getIndex) otherwise.

I know I could set up a redirect, but I'd like to just handle it all within routing.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if this way is possible.  You have two locations assigned to the same route location, and declare that you want auth before reaching that location.  You could use nested views in the home page and require Auth::check() before the login view and else to the normal home page or something. Otherwise I don't know if you would be able to route 2 separate pages to the same location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your own auth filter

```
if(!Auth::check()){
    return Route::get('/', 'PageController@getIndex');
} else {
    Route::controller('/',            'HomeController'); 
}
```

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that this won't work if you use route caching in the later versions of Laravel (I believe 5.1 and up ship with that feature).